# Is it safe to delete a .bin file on an Android 11 phone?

Tags: security, file-system, delete, cache

I keep getting .bin files that show zero data in them and others that pop up regularly. Is it safe to delete them? Do they contain any vital information. Are they remnants of sites I've visited using my Android 11 phone? Can I do without them or am I causing some harm in deleting them? Some show up on engine log. What are they?

Comment: Where are those files located at? Without any more details, it might be difficult for us to determine. Consider [edit]ing and providing more details.

Comment: yes you can delete that files it won't harm your device